# AWS CDK - Cannot assume role in Lambda for fine grained authorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, serverless, aws-cdk, aws-serverless

I am fairly new in AWS specifics, so forgive me a stupid question.
I was looking for the answers, but I did not find any question answering my issue.

I am building a project and I am trying to get the permissions done right using this AWS tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/partitioning-pooled-multi-tenant-saas-data-with-amazon-dynamodb/

I have created role and policy:

```js
const tenantUserRole = new Role(this, "TenantUserRole", {
      assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
    });
table.grantReadWriteData(tenantUserRole);
```

Then, in my Lambda I am trying to:

```js
const role = await stsClient.send(
    new AssumeRoleCommand({
      Policy: getPolicy("tenant"),
      RoleArn: process.env.TENANT_ROLE_ARN,
      RoleSessionName: "foo",
    })
  );
```

This does not work as I am getting an error in Lambda:

> {
> "errorType": "AccessDenied",
> "errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/ProjectStack-createUserServiceRoleB9D8AADE-GRDI6MWXA5MY/ProjectStack-createUserC6ED88E6-K0S95UXTN9MH is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/ProjectStack-TenantUserRoleB79B8D3A-11N644X7UF0SR",
> "trace": [
> "AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/ProjectStack-createUserServiceRoleB9D8AADE-GRDI6MWXA5MY/ProjectStack-createUserC6ED88E6-K0S95UXTN9MH is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/ProjectStack-TenantUserRoleB79B8D3A-11N644X7UF0SR",

The target is to always resolve permissions based on the user context, so what should I do in my CDK stack to enable all my Lambdas to do what has to be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As described by @Maurice, the role should be trusted instead of the service principal(`lambda.amazonaws.com`).
Below is the CDK code.

`TenantUserRole` trusted by `apiRole` which is being used by `aws lambda`

```js
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as iam from '@aws-cdk/aws-iam';

export class CdkWorkshopStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    // aws lambda role
    const lambdaRole = new iam.Role(this, 'apiRole', {
      roleName: 'apiRole',
      assumedBy:  new iam.ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com'),
    });
    // trusted by TenantUserRole for access
    const tenantUserRole = new iam.Role(this, 'TenantUserRole', {
      roleName: 'TenantUserRole',
      assumedBy: new iam.ArnPrincipal(lambdaRole.roleArn),
    });

    // policy to allow assume role TenantUserRole
    lambdaRole.addToPolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        resources: [tenantUserRole.roleArn],
        actions: ['sts:AssumeRole'],
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Here it looks like in role's trust policy.

```bash
❯❯ aws  iam get-role --role-name TenantUserRole
{
    "Role": {
        "Path": "/",
        "RoleName": "TenantUserRole",
        "RoleId": "AROA2WXKNDTKKGFADASD",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/TenantUserRole",
        "CreateDate": "2021-03-03T23:34:13+00:00",
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/apiRole"
                    },
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Description": "",
        "MaxSessionDuration": 3600,
        "RoleLastUsed": {}
    }
}
```

Policy to allow aws lambda role to assume `TenantUserRole`

```bash
❯❯ aws iam get-role-policy  --role-name apiRole  --policy-name apiRoleDefaultPolicy771DC0DD
{
    "RoleName": "apiRole",
    "PolicyName": "apiRoleDefaultPolicy771DC0DD",
    "PolicyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/TenantUserRole",
                "Effect": "Allow"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[How to use trust policies with IAM roles](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-trust-policies-with-iam-roles/)

In lambda you need to after assuming the `TenantUserRole` you need to use those credentials and create `dynamodb` client and then use that client for making the api call `putItem`

```py
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sts = boto3.client('sts')
    // assume TenantUserRole
    creds = sts.assume_role(
        RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/TenantUserRole',
        RoleSessionName="tempsession"
        )
    // Use Credentials from the assume call to make dynamodb client
    tenant_user_dyanmodb_client = boto3.client(
    'dynamodb',
    aws_access_key_id=creds.get('Credentials').get('AccessKeyId'),
    aws_secret_access_key=creds.get('Credentials').get('SecretAccessKey'),
    aws_session_token=creds.get('Credentials').get('SessionToken')
    )

   // call put item
    tenant_user_dyanmodb_client.put_item(TableName='fruitSalad', Item={'fruitName':{'S':'Banana'},'key2':{'N':'value2'}})
```

Comment: I think the part that allows the apiRole to call sts:AssumeRole on the TenantUserRole is missing, but OP should be able to figure that out :-)

Comment: @Maurice I wanted to share the `trust policy` example, and he can go along with policies easily. I can add that too, if needed. I took the example from his post where is allowing by service principal, as he mentioned <I  have created role and policy>

Comment: That's fair - I just wanted to point out, that this brings OP closer to their goal, but they will still see an AccessDenied until they also add the assume role permissions to the apiRole.

Comment: sure @Maurice I added the second part too,  just to make both your points valid. Thanks much for reviewing the post. Have a good day!

Comment: I am almost there thanks to this answer.
The issue I have is that when I call DynamoDB I get an error that `apiRole` does not permission to call Dynamo, while at the beginning of the Lambda I call `assumeRole` with success (credentials are there).
In the linked AWS article, there is `boto3.session` using result from the `assumeRole` result and I suppose that is the reason, but I cannot find how to do that in Node

Comment: User: arn:aws:sts::227973151364:assumed-role/apiRole/ProjectStack-createUserC6ED88E6-K0S95UXTN9MH is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource...

Comment: @MarekUrbanowicz I was assuming your `TenantUserRole` has access to `dynamodb`. Can you confirm?

Comment: It does: `table.grantReadWriteData(tenantUserRole);`
As you see on the error it looks like it does not use TenantUserRole, but still `apiRole`

Interesting fact is that it was working same way (error, but getting credentials for the role) without adding the policy which you added with edit

Comment: @MarekUrbanowicz you need to use the credentials from `assume-role` call to make `dynamodb` client and then use that client for `putItem`

Comment: I've tried like this:
```
  const documentClient = new DocumentClient({
    // @ts-ignore
    credentials: role.Credentials,
  });
```
but it then throws: "errorType": "CredentialsError",
  "errorMessage": "Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229508/discussion-between-samtoddler-and-marek-urbanowicz).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a misunderstanding concerning who is the principal.

When you're inside a Lambda function trying to call other AWS API operations, it's **not** actually the service `lambda.amazonaws.com` that does the call, but instead the role which the Lambda function assumes.

This means instead of allowing the service `lambda.amazonaws.com` to assume your `TenantUserRole`, you need to allow the role that the function uses to assume that role.

You need to both configure the assume role policy as well as the permissions of the lambda functions' role in order to allow it to call `sts:AssumeRole`.

Comment: Could you please explain with CDK code? I understand to some degree but don't know how to translate it to CDK?